# Why does saber mean both "to know" and "to taste"?

Tags: definiciones, verbos, etimología

## Español

Cuando estudiaba español, estaba muy confundido cuando aprendí que *saber* significa "to know" y "to taste". Los dos verbos en inglés me parecen muy diferentes. ¿Cómo puede ser esto? ¿Cuál es la etimología de *saber*? ¿Existen algunas situaciones similares con "to know" y "to taste" en otros idiomas?

---

## English

When learning Spanish, I was very confused when I learned that *saber* means both "to know" and "to taste." The two English verbs seem very different to me. How did this come to be? What is the etymology of *saber*, and are there similar situations with "to know" and "to taste" in other languages?

Comment: The part of the question about other languages would probably get a much better/thorough answer on Linguistics.

Comment: Vale: 7. intr. Dicho de una cosa, especialmente de algo comestible: Tener un determinado sabor. La salsa sabía muy fuerte. Esta sopa sabe A ajo. Pero también se dice: tener un gusto de....

Comment: I notice that "taste" in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tastes) includes the following definition: "to become acquainted with by experience".  It also lists "know" as a synonym.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Español

De hecho, puedes encontrar rastros de ese tipo de coincidencias también en inglés.

- Un *savant* es una persona que sabe mucho. A pesar de que es un préstamo del francés, se usa bastante en inglés. Un *sage* es también una persona sabia, alguien que sabe mucho.
- Un plato *savoury* es un plato salado o condimentado, lo cual se refiere al sabor.

Los dos términos "sage" (o "savant") y "savoury" están relacionados con el latín *sapĕre*, muy similar a "saber" en español que, como dice el OP, quiere decir igualmente "to know" y "to taste". Tienen el mismo origen.

Igualmente en francés tenemos *savoir* ("to know") y *saveur* ("taste"). La explicación es similar.

Nota. Hay que tener en cuenta que *saber* ("to taste") se refiere solo al sabor de las cosas, por ejemplo "este pastel sabe genial" ("this cake tastes great"); no puede usarse para expresar el acto de probar o saborear algo, por ejemplo "would you like to taste the cake?" o "let me taste it", en estos casos, los verbos correctos en Español son *probar* o *saborear*.

---

## English

Actually, you can find traces of that coincidence in English too:

- A *savant* is someone who knows a lot. Although this is a loan from French, it is used in English often enough. A *sage* is also a wise person, one who knows a lot.
- A *savoury* dish is a salty or spicy one. This refers to the quality of taste.

Both "sage" (or "savant") and "savoury" are related to the Latin *sapĕre*, very much like the Spanish "saber" which, as the OP says, means both "to know" and "to taste". They have a common origin.

Also, in French, we have *savoir* ("to know") and *saveur* ("taste"). Similar explanation.

Side note. Please note that *saber* (as in "to taste") refers only to how something tastes, e.g. "this cake tastes great" (*este pastel sabe genial*); it cannot be used to express one tasting something, e.g. "would you like to taste the cake?" or "let me taste it"; in these cases, the correct Spanish verbs would be *probar* or *saborear*.

Answer (score 5):

Los dos "saberes" (el del gusto y el de la sabiduría) tienen un pasado en común. El "saber" original es el del gusto. Derivó al segundo significado por una metáfora en latín que también aparece en otros idiomas. La palabra latina "sapere" parece provenir de la antiquísima raíz proto-indoeuropea *sap- ("tantear").

"Sapere" originalmente se refería a "percibir", "oler", tal como en expresiones españolas del tipo "esto me huele a trampa". Pero su uso principal en latín vulgar era el que quedó en las palabras españolas "sabor", "sabroso", "saborear", "insípido", "resabio", "desabrido" y "sinsabores", vale decir, relativo al sentido del gusto.

Por una metáfora conceptual extraña pero al parecer frecuente, el "saber" de *sentir el gusto* se usó para referirse a asuntos más espirituales, del mismo modo que nosotros usamos los sentidos del sistema nervioso en expresiones como "*esta diseñadora tiene muy buen **gusto***", "*me **gustó** mucho tu libro*", "*ellos se **gustan***", "*díselo con **tacto***" y "*es un **visionario** de los negocios*".

Entonces el "saber" paso a tener primero una connotación y después un significado relacionados con la capacidad intelectual de percepción, algo parecido al "sentido común". De aquí vienen la otra familia de palabras españolas: "sabiduría", "sabio", "sabiondo", "saberes", "sabelotodo". Además, por supuesto, está nuestra querida especie: "*Homo sapiens*".

Y un último asunto: ambos verbos se conjugan de igual forma.

> Tú sabes leer muy bien.
>
> Tú sabes a menta. ;)
>
> Yo sé hablar en alemán.
>
> Yo sé a sal.

Comment: Pues yo creo que sí responde a la pregunta, y bastante bien (de hecho creo que responde mejor que la respuesta aceptada) ya que explica la etimología de las palabras y porqué son homófonas. Ninguna de las otras respuestas ofrece eso.

Comment: De acuerdo completamente con @Diego. Ya me había hecho yo esta pregunta hace muchos años y me ha agradado mucho leer esta respuesta. En mi época de secundaria, incluso le pregunté a mi profesor de lengua si era correcto decir "sé a sal" (¡casualmente!), ya que suena un tanto extraño, a lo que me respondió afirmativamente.

Comment: Lo que ahora me parece bastante intrigante es cómo una rama ha pasado a decirse «al revés» que la otra: *el guiso sabe bien*; *yo sé cocinar*. Es decir, que «guiso» (el objeto) sea el sujeto gramatical en el «caso sabor» y «yo» (la persona) lo sea en el «caso saber».

Comment: En tercera persona también se dicen igual: el guiso _sabe_ bien, el cocinero _sabe_ cocinar.

Answer (score 2):

One way of getting to "know" something is to "taste" it.

Of course, one can get similar "knowledge," by seeing, hearing, feeling, or smelling. But "tasting" is the arguably the most intimate.

Comment: And smell is the "knowledge" we remember the most out of all five

Answer (score 1):

Saber (al gusto) es un verbo intransitivo.

Saber (aprendizaje) es un verbo transitivo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about other languages having the same verb with those two meanings ("to know" and "to taste"). But we might have a similar example with "sentir", which means "to feel" and "to smell" in French and "to feel", "to hear" and "to regret" in Spanish.

That said, it might be easier to understand how a verb meaning "to feel" (as was the case with "sentio" in Latin) came to develop a more specific meaning of feeling through one of the five senses.